# Terminal window cannot find git executable (Rstudio 1.1.331)

Tags: rstudio

I have a fully functional git-bash terminal (newest version installed today), but the new preview version of Rstudio says:

```
bash: git: command not found
```

Standard bash commands do work fine. Outside of Rstudio my terminal does find git.

Windows 7, Rstudio 1.1.331, git 2.14.1-windows.1

(As a sidenote, also installed same Rstudio version on my Win10 laptop, there the terminal windows in Rstudio did find git).

Comment: What's the output of `echo $PATH` in your terminal? Where is your `git` executable located?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also saw this problem when I installed Git 2.14.1 for Windows, and on the Adjusting your PATH setup screen, chose **Use Git from Git Bash only**.

**To fix**, close RStudio, reinstall Git (no need to uninstall it) and this time select **Use Git from the Windows Command Prompt** and the RStudio terminal should now be able to find git. Let me know if that works for you (or not!).

Comment: Selecting 'Use git from the windows command prompt' fixed it.

Comment: Setting the path to "C:\Program Files\Git\cmd" fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

I get this resolved by moving **UP** the git path in the $PATH environmental variable (windows). Now RStudio can 'see' the git bash option. I found this solution through googling around, but I wasn't able to find the original source any more.